# Call to undefined method PHP_CodeCoverage_Filter::addDirectoryToBlacklist()

Tags: php, phpunit

I tried running PHP in my code and it shows

```
$ ./vendor/bin/phpunit
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method PHP_CodeCoverage_Filter::addDirectoryToBlacklist() in /home/petra/myproject/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/TestRunner.php on line 979
```

Previously it's running normal.

Here's in the `composer.json`

```
"require-dev": {
    ...
    "phpunit/phpunit": "4.6.*", 
    ...
}
```

Here's the content of `phpunit.xml`.

```
<phpunit bootstrap="./test/bootstrap.php">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Test">
            <directory>./test</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

The content of `./test/bootstrap.php` is just this

```
require dirname(__FILE__) . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tried manually set the `phpunit/php-code-coverage` dependency to `2.2.4` and this works.